# Depth First Search Example

Tags: graph, complexity-theory, depth-first-search

I have a Depth First Search example for a practice exam and I have asked another question regarding it and I think I have some of the concepts of it down...

I just want to confirm the results I got are correct or not, and if you can guide me what I did wrong and how I can fix it.

Here is a picture of it:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiWB5.png

The results I got for DFI in order from 0 - 8 are :

1     5     7     6     2     3     4     8     9

For parent, I got confused because it starts at 0, the parent of 0 is 4? and the parent of 4 is 5? I am confused with parent, so if someone can clarify that my results for DFI are correct / wrong , and also help me with Parent, I would GREATLY appreciate it. This is all practice review for an exam.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: This question is not a practical programming problem but is rather a theoretical one. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a DFS on this graph starting from 0, then one example of the order you will visit the vertices is 
**{0, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 7, 8, 2}**. The parent of each of the vertices from the given order (as represented by (vertex, parent) pairs) would be **{(0,-)(4,0),(5,4),(6,0),(1,6),(3,1),(7,3),(8,3),(2,6)}**  [image: Example graph]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry about that! Changed the explanation to DFS.

Answer (score 0):

DFI looks ok to me.
The DFI tells you the order in which the nodes are found. Does not necessarily give you the information on parent.
The node you start from should not have any parent, since that is the root of your DFS tree. Have a look at the DFI, 0 is visited before any other node. That is why it has 1 in DFI.
Then next is 4, which has DFI 2. Since 4 is found from 0, its parent is 0. Then you found 5 from 4, so 5 should have parent 4. Then you traced back to 0. And so on for the rest of the graph.

Comment: I believe you mean 4 should be the parent of 5. Correct me if I'm wrong, thanks.